# OpenERP 7 share XML-file with 3th party application

Tags: python, rest, odoo, xml-rpc, edi

Hi I'd like to receive XML-files from a third party application. I thought of using REST, but this is not available in OpenERP 7. Any other solutions to do so. The XML-files contains Invoice data, when one is received a new record of the account.invoice has to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shared Folder via SFTP

Do you mean that you don´t have [`XMLRPC`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html) available? You can share a local server folder (by `sftp` for instance) and the third party application can leave the files there temporary. When you process the file you can already delete it.

### Alternative to XMLRPC >> JSONRPC and Controllers

You can use [**controllers**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/http.html) as well, but you need to use JSONRPC here. Maybe you can include the plain xml file into one JSON field.

But I think controllers were built only for OpenERP internal purposes. Check the problems I had about this: [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848963/how-to-send-a-simple-message-and-status-as-a-response-in-an-odoo-json-controller), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915198/when-should-i-use-xml-rpc-instead-of-a-controller-in-odoo)

**Note**: Take into account that with this solution you will need to use only one database in the OpenERP instance.

### Process XML File

If you want to read the XML file you can use the [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) library. Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912483/4891717):

> After building an Element instance `e` from the XML, e.g. with the XML
>   function, or by parsing a file with something like
>
> ```
> import xml.etree.ElementTree
> e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('thefile.xml').getroot()
> ```
>
> or any of the many other ways shown at `ElementTree`, you just do
>   something like:
>
> ```
> for atype in e.findall('type'):
>     print(atype.get('foobar'))
> ```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this solution but I find this less attractive. I'd like to use a RESTful service to transfer the XML data. I was wondering if there was a solution to use this with OpenERP V7

Comment: OK, I have added another option. Check if it is helpful for you

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this one